# Spring @Async limit number of threads

Tags: multithreading, spring, asynchronous, thread-synchronization

My question is very similar to this one : [@Async prevent a thread to continue until other thread have finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324212/async-prevent-a-thread-to-continue-until-other-thread-have-finished)

Basically i need run ~ hundreds of computations in more threads. I want to run only some amount of parallel threads e.g. 5 threads with 5 computationis in paralell.

I am using spring framework and @Async option is natural choice. I do not need full-featured JMS queue, that`s a bit overhead for me.

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you checked out `Task Executor`? You can define a Thread Pool, with a maximum number of threads to execute your tasks.

If you want to use it with `@Async`, use this in your spring-config:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

Full reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) (25.5.3). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using Spring's Java-configuration, your config class needs to implements `AsyncConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    [...]

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

See `@EnableAsync` documentation for more details : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html

Comment: what if I need multiple asyncs?

Comment: You may annotate several methods with `@Async` and they will share the thread pool / executor defined with `@EnableAsync` config.

Comment: I mean - several executors with different configurations for each

Comment: I have never done it, but I think it is possible by defining your own annotation (e.g. `@MyAsync1` and `@MyAsync2`) and then using two `@EnableAsync` (on two distinct configuration classes) while specifying the `annotation` parameter : `@EnableAsync(annotation = @MyAsync1.class)` and `@EnableAsync(annotation = @MyAsync2.class)`. See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html#annotation--) of the `@EnableAsync` class

Comment: for having multiple executors with different configurations, you can have a look link : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async. The section 4.1 tells  you how to name the executor and use it like @Async("<executor name>")

Comment: If I set queue capacity to 50 which is full and suppose my core pool size threads are not complete, what happens to my 51st task? will it get rejected or will the Async method caller wait?

Comment: @KCK It is general thread pool functionality, you can read more on that here for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadpooltaskexecutor-core-vs-max-poolsize

Answer (score 18):

**Since spring boot 2.1** you can use auto configuration and change the maximum number of threads in the application properties file

```
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=4
```

See the full documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling