# Issue with Spring Boot Async method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-async

I have a asynchronous method enabled using @Async annotation. At times i am seeing [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) thread count increases exponentially. Any idea on this behavior?

Comment: Have you configured CustomThreadPool?

Comment: No i haven't configured CustomThreadPool

Comment: It is better if you configure the customThreadPool.Check this out.                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206792/spring-async-limit-number-of-threads

Answer (score 0):

If it increases literally exponentially it sounds like the async method is calling itself perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring uses a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor to run the methods asynchronously.
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor spawns a new thread with each task and does not support thread pooling and queueing of tasks.
So, if the async method is called multiple times in a short span of time, multiple threads will be opened for each task
You should define your own executor. Refer the following link
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async